# How to redirect all http requests to https using nginx for react

Tags: reactjs, nginx, nginx-config

Here is my Nginx config for my react app

```
server {
    listen 8080 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:8080 ssl default_server;

    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    # ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/privatekey.pem;

    root /home/ubuntu/project-folder/dist/;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;


    error_page 404 /index.html;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

The SSL is enabled it working for https://website.co:8080 but not working on https://website.co and how to redirect if an HTTP request comes? how to handle?

Comment: You should listen to port 443 in addition to 8080. 443 is the default port used for https, and will be used if the url does not specify a specific port.

Comment: When it is running in 8080 without SSL it is available on 80 too. Can't that happen that it available on 8080 and 443 at the same time?

Comment: Please check my question now I have added 443 too. BUt still the same.

Comment: Just set 2 different server brackets, one for 80, and another one for 443

Comment: No it didnt work. I have added 80 in another server